# Why are my violet leaves no longer pointing up?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, leaves

When I bought these violets, the leaves were pointing up. Now, they seem healthy and are even flowering,  but the leaves are going downwards. What makes them point up or lay down like that?

[image: Other with laying down leaves but otherwise healthy]

[image: My violet flowering with leaves laying in the pot]

They looked like these originally:

[image: They looked like these originally]

Comment: They do that as new leaves grow. You are watering from the bottom, with a little fertilizer once a week? I've been doing that for over a decade with some of mine. They're huge, and almost constantly in bloom.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger, I water from the top, not wetting the leaves. I have not yet started to fertilize, because I intend to prepare an organic fertilizer for my orchids and will use it in the violets as well, but have to check if all ingredients are fine for the violet. So many doubts!

Comment: @Caroliba Faria, IMHO, that should be an ideal posture for an Afr. Violet, pointing upward leaves is usually linked with things such as reaching upward for light(not enough light), protecting the center from hot air (direct sunlight), and some unchangeable genetical conditions. As long  it doesn't come from the overwatering condition then they are fine.probably it just a form of adaptaion to air, humidity, temperature ij your room.

Answer (score 1):

As Wayfaring Stranger has pointed out it happens as new leaves grow. If you look carefully at the crown, as your plants get older you may note that the shape changes from a little round bump to a vertically extended shape. Imagine a pencil being pushed up through the soil - at first the leaves grow out of the flat or rounded top of the eraser and stand up straight. Then as new growth happens at the eraser tip they push the old leaves to the outside; the "pencil" emerges further, the old leaves are no longer at the top where the eraser is, they are now growing out of the sides of the pencil, out of a vertical surface and therefore the petioles are horizontal.

The upright tube shape becomes clearer as the plant moves into old age and needs renewal.

Comment: I am skeptical of this explanation because they became like this too shorty after the purchase. Sun or watering problems were my guesses, but I am following the water when dirt is 2 cm dry and give it plenty of indirect light instructions.